# Is there a good reason to split related datasets into different SQL databases rather than just tables?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-express

This question is motivated by a recent update to some business software a friend of mine is using. Their architecture was based on Access databases until now, which was awfully slow. They had split their datasets into multiple mdb files (sales.mdb, products.mdb, stock.mdb, ...). They are now moving on to SQL Server Express and keeping this structure. Instead of using a table for each of these datasets, they created different databases on the same instance of SQL Server 2008 Express.

From my (admittedly limited) understanding of SQL Server, this does not seem sensible, as it prevents JOINs between different tables and requires a program that needs sales and stock data to maintain two DB connections instead of just one.

One of the software vendor's consultants claimed that this would circumvent SQL Express' RAM limit of 1GB physical memory - he says that is per-database, but from what I gather from MSDN, it's actually per-instance, so they win nothing here.

Is there a good reason for splitting data in the same business domain into databases rather than tables?
(One that I can think of is that you can restrict access per database, but not per table - but this is irrelevant in this particular case, all modules of the program can access all databases.)

Comment: Splitting load across a server farm makes sense.  It sounds like your application isn't that big.  You can restrict access to individual objects (table, views, stored procedures, ...) within a single database, so that isn't likely to be an issue.  The benefits of foreign keys, a useful transaction log, ..., would seem to tip the balance toward one database.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! The application is not that big. Max 30 concurrent users, tables have a maximum of 1M rows, queries on non-indexed columns are rare. Only a single server.

Comment: Taking consistent backups would be my concern - the unit of backup and recovery is (generally) the database (you can subdivide down to filegroups).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write joins across databases, so that's not a major issue. Generally, I would suggest keeping everything in one database unless there was a very good reason to split it, and those reasons might have something to do with compatibility, say where you had an application that had to run against a database in compatibility mode 80 or something - you might choose to separate some data into a separate database at that compatibility level. Or if you had a major chunk of functionality that you wanted to be able to easily move to another server - say data migration, or ETL.

It sounds like the limitation is in the application.

Comment: Joins across different databases - didn't know that, very interesting! Would that also be possible across different server instances?

Comment: Yes, it is possible with some hoop-jumping, but it is not a good idea.  The engine has access to statistics across an instance, but as soon as you go outside that, it has no idea WRT data distribution. This often results in serious performance problems. Don't do it.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your version of SQL Server Express, splitting the databases up could allow for more data storage (2005 has a 4GB db limitation, 2008 is 10GB).

An addition to the 1GB RAM per instance limit, I believe SQL Server Express is also limited to 1 CPU per instance as well.

I would agree with HABO's comment. You cannot enforce referential integrity across databases, that will all have to be managed within the application.